# Deploying using npm surge issue

Tags: deployment, npm, surge.sh

I'm trying to deploy my web project using `surge`. I have done this successfully on previous occasions. But now i'm getting an error and cannot understand why this happens.

```
              email: g****n5**5@yahoo.com
              token: *****************
              project path: C:\Users\admin\Documents\r*******r-ui-development\build\
               size: 44 files, 11.8 MB
             domain: r*******r-ui.surge.sh

             upload: [=======             ] 34%, eta: 9.7s{ Error: write ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1023:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:804:14) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'write' }
{ Error: write ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1023:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:804:14) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'write' }
```

What seems to be the problem here? And how could i fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with the internet connection I was using. Apparently, the wifi network had some restrictions. I solved this by using a hotspot created from my mobile, and it worked perfectly. This was not an issue with npm.